# How to add a custom attribute to a product view in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, custom-attributes, product-view, custom-theme

I created the attribute with code "supplier" in my admin area,

besides, I saved the file "mycustomblock.phtml" in "/app/design/frontend/{MyThemeName}/default/etc/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/"

with this code:

```
<?php
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$label = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('supplier')->getStoreLabel(); 
$value = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('supplier')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); 
echo '<div class="divWeight"><div class="labelWeight">'.$label.':</div> <div class="valueWeight">'.$value."</div></div>";
?>
```

Then I edited the file "/app/design/frontend/{MyThemeName}/default/etc/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml"

like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>

        <!-- mycustomblock -->
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.mycustomblock" as="mycustomblock" template="product/view/mycustomblock.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
                <arguments>
                     <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">mycustomblock</argument>
                     <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">mycustomblock</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>

        <!-- mycustomblock position -->
        <move element="product.info.mycustomblock" destination="product.info.social" after="product.info.stock.sku"/>



        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="banner.sidebar" after="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">cms-static-banner-sidebar</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="product.sidebar" after="banner.sidebar">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">cms-static-latest-product-sidebar</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="policy.sidebar" after="product.sidebar">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">cms-static-policy</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <referenceBlock name="wishlist_sidebar" remove="true"/>
            <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>
        <move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main"/>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="product.essential" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-essential" before="-">
               <container name="product.detail" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="row" before="-">
                    <container name="product.info.media" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-media product media" />
                    <container name="product.info.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-main product-shop" after="product.info.media">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.review" template="product/view/review.phtml" before="-" />
                        <container name="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" label="Product View Extra Hint">
                            <container name="product.info.social" label="Product social links container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-social-links" before="product.info.overview">
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="product/view/addto.phtml"/>
                                <referenceBlock name="product.info.mailto" remove="true" />
                            </container>
                        </container>

                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.overview" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info" before="product.price.final" after="product.info.stock.sku">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getShortDescription</argument>
                                <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">short_description</argument>
                                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">overview</argument>
                                <argument name="at_label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Overview</argument>
                                <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="description"</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.final" after="product.info.overview">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                                <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">final_price</argument>
                                <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info" template="product/view/form.phtml" after="product.price.final" before="product.info.details">
                            <container name="product.info.form.content" as="product_info_form_content">
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
                            </container>
                            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product.info.form.options" as="options_container">
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="product/view/options/wrapper.phtml">
                                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="product/view/options.phtml">
                                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType" as="default" template="product/view/options/type/default.phtml"/>
                                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text" as="text" template="product/view/options/type/text.phtml"/>
                                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File" as="file" template="product/view/options/type/file.phtml"/>
                                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" as="select" template="product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>
                                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date" as="date" template="product/view/options/type/date.phtml"/>
                                    </block>
                                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="Magento_Theme::js/calendar.phtml"/>
                                </block>
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml">
                                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart.additional" as="product.info.addtocart" template="product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
                                </block>
                            </block>
                        </block>

                    </container>
                    <!-- end product main info -->
                </container>
            </container> 
            <!-- end detail box -->
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Finally, I flushed, cleaned the cache and reindexed.

However, the attribute is not shown, neither the label nor the value.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  need to add `catalog_product_view.xml` file here in this path in your theme

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Content for this file is ..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.mycustomblock" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/mycustomblock.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="product.info.mycustomblock" destination="product.info.social" after="product.info.stock.sku" />
    </body>
</page>
```

- After adding above xml file you need to create one template file here..

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/mycustomblock.phtml

Content for this file is ..

```
<?php
    $_product = $block->getProduct();
    $label = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('supplier')->getStoreLabel(); 
    $value = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('supplier')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); 
    echo '<div class="divWeight"><div class="labelWeight">'.$label.':</div> <div class="valueWeight">'.$value."</div></div>";
?>
```

You can change content based on your requirement.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: In my template folder "app/design/frontend/Alothemes/demo3/" doesn't exists the folder Magento_Catalog. I created the folders and files but nothing appear....

Comment: You need to create template and layout both files as per answer and then you need to run cache:clean and cache:flush commands once